# Rails actioncable alias request origins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket, actioncable

I have an application with subdomains and I would like to be able to connect to a WebSocket of all of the subdomains when I add a subdomain to
`cable/config.ru`

```
ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins = ["domain.com",
 "sub1.domain.com", "sub1.domain.com"]
```

It works ok but how I can set alias for all subdomains 
somethink like this:

```
"[*.domain.com]"
```

Char " * "dosn't work.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you use ActionCable on production level? Or you are just playing with it?

Answer (score 7):

[Actioncable now supports regular expressions](https://github.com/rails/actioncable/pull/130)

Usage denoted below:

> Action Cable will only accept requests from specified origins, which
>   are passed to the server config as an array. The origins can be
>   instances of strings or regular expressions, against which a check for
>   match will be performed.

`ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins = ['http://rubyonrails.com', /http:\/\/ruby.*/]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for this case.
In environments files (production and development) use this:

`config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/(?:^(http|https):\/\/)?(?:([^.]+)\.)?#{ENV["domain"]}/]`

As the ENV["domain"] the domain that the application runs in.

Answer (score 0):

**[OUTDATED ANSWER]**

It seems that something like this is not implemented yet from the current implementation of ActionCable on its official [repo](https://github.com/rails/actioncable/blob/63cdbf87ddaeb6bbc852de7ca2c504b7f6a22321/lib/action_cable/connection/base.rb#L175) on GitHub.